# Specification for filter joining multiple tables, including embedded primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, repository, hibernate-criteria

I want to build a `Specification` to filter a property that is not directly included in the entity but in the "second join".

The entities look (much simplified) like this:

```java
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy=pk.a)
    private List<B> b;
}

@Entity
public class B {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PK pk;
}

@Embeddable
public class PK {
    @ManyToOne
    private A a;
    
    @ManyToOne
    private C c;
}

@Entity
public class C {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy=pk.b)
    private List<B> b;
}
```

I want to get all A that have a specific C.id and I already have a repository method by name that is working:

```java
List<A> findAllByBPKCId(String id);
```

Since I want some more filters I need to move to `JpaSpecificationExecutor` but I'm failing to build the `Specification` to do the same than the previous repository method.

What I tried so far is:
Calling

```java
List<A> findAll(Specification specification);
```

with

```java
new Specification() {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder criteraBuilder) {
        return criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join("b").join(pk.c).get("id"), ID_TO_COMPARE);
    }
}
```

However it won't find "pk.c", I need to somehow "get" pk first before joining c. It throws an IllegalArgumentException because it is 'Unable to locate Attribute with the given name [pk.b]'.

How can I join an entity that is nested in an embedded "composite primary key"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first join `B` and `PK`, and then join with `C`, i.e., `PK` should be consider the same way as the rest of entities when joining.

Please, consider the following code:

```java
new Specification() {
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder criteraBuilder) {
        Join<A, B> joinAB = root.join("b");
        Join<B, PK> joinBPK = joinAB.join("pk");
        Join<PK, C> joinPKC = joinBPK.join("c");

        return criteraBuilder.equal(joinPKC.get("id"), cb.literal(ID_TO_COMPARE));
    }
}
```

This code can be simplified using lambdas:

```java
public static Specification<A> getSpecification(String ID_TO_COMPARE) {
  return (root, query, cb) -> {
    Join<A, B> joinAB = root.join("b");
    Join<B, PK> joinBPK = joinAB.join("pk");
    Join<PK, C> joinPKC = joinBPK.join("c");

    return cb.equal(joinPKC.get("id"), cb.literal(ID_TO_COMPARE));
  };
}
```

In addition, if you have the opportunity, use [criteria metamodel](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-criteria-metamodel/), it provides compilation type field checking when constructing your queries and makes the things clear:

```java
public static Specification<A> getSpecification(String ID_TO_COMPARE) {
  return (root, query, cb) -> {
    Join<A, B> joinAB = root.join(A_.b);
    Join<B, PK> joinBPK = joinAB.join(B_.pk);
    Join<PK, C> joinPKC = joinBPK.join(PK_.c);

    return cb.equal(joinPKC.get(C_.id), cb.literal(ID_TO_COMPARE));
  };
}
```

Comment: @Jens Yesterday, I modified the answer in order to include your code instead of lambdas. Were you able to test the solution? I'm quite confident about its correctness, specially when using the criteria metamodel. Did it work in your use case?

Comment: Yea sorry, took me some days to come back to this topic. It worked perfectly, thank you. :) My problem was, that I didn't know that I can join the Embeddable like an entity instead of getting it like a property.

Comment: Please there is not need to apologize. You are very welcome @Jens. I am very happy to hear that you were able to solve the problem.